# Subselect fetching strategy doesn't work on nested collections in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 entities and nested collections of them as follows:
entity A contains collection of B, entity B contains collection of C.

And I need to fetch a list of full object graphs of entity A. When I set fetching strategy to "subselect" both for collection of B and collection of C, actually only collection of B is read via single query. Each collection of C is read via separate query per each entity of type B - the same as if fetching strategy was "select" there.

So I expect the following:

```
select ... from A
select ... from B where a_id in (select id from A)
select ... from C where b_id in (select id from B where a_id in (select id from A))
```

But actually get:

```
select ... from A
select ... from B where a_id in (select id from A)
select ... from C where b_id = ?
select ... from C where b_id = ?
...
select ... from C where b_id = ?
```

Are there any limitations on nested subselects?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been identified - entities mapped to the database have custom implementation of getHashCode() which calculates hash code based on values of all internal members including collections. When Hibernate calls getHashCode() for entity B, collection C is not read yet but it is necessary for getting the hash. So a separate query is executed to get the collection of C for current object B...